# Dynamically generate output based on the argument passed to the compiler

Tags: sectioning, enumerate, compiling, itemize

Say I have a document like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{one}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first item.
\item This is the second item.
\item This is the third item.

\end{enumerate}
\section{two}
bla bla blabla
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to force the order of items in the enumerate tag and  the order of sections based on an argument passed during compilation.

I need this for my CV where I sometimes need to emphasise (list them at the top) my skills in physics and sometime my skills in electronics ( depending on the context ). I could maintain two different CV's but thats too much of work. I was wodering if something like this exists.

Comment: You can mimick in LaTeX a template based approach by moving all contents to other files, use `\input{filename}` to incorporate them, prepare various chunks of such sequences of `\input`, and either use conditionals depending on some flag you set at top of document, or simply comment them out as needed. Conditionals can help you compile from command line passing a suitable macro definition so you may never have to modify main document once all `\input` are prepared therein, and concentrate on editing "contents" files.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to define your "special" sections in the preamble and then use a variable/macro to specify the order that they are inserted into your document. Below I show one way to do this. I have used [latex3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) to give a slightly swish interface to control the variants that are printed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mylist{
\section{one}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first item.
\item This is the second item.
\item This is the third item.
\end{enumerate}
}

\newcommand\blah{
\section{two}
bla bla blabla
}

\usepackage{expl3}

% set a default
\providecommand\cvversion{listblah}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\mycv{
  \str_case:xn {\cvversion} {
    {listblah} { \mylist \blah}
    {blahlist} { \blah \mylist }
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn {xn}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \mycv

\end{document}
```

So `\mylist` and `\blah` are the two bits of the contents that you want to print in different places and the `\mycv` macro is used to print them in to the required order depending on the value of `\cvversion`. By default, `\mylist` is printed before `\blah` but if you set `\cvversion to`blahlist` you will get them in the reverse order.

You can set `\cvversion` from the command line using something like

```
pdflatex "\def\cvverson{blahlist}\input{filename}"
```

where `filename` is replaced by the name of the file. I'd do this differently by either creating multiple version of the cv that look like

```
% blahlist version
\newcommand\cvversion{blashlist}
\input filename
```

or using symbolic links and then using `\jobbname` to set `\cvversion accordingly (in which case you would not need the macro`\cvversion` at all....).

Finally, note that my macro above does not do any error checking. This is probably OK in your use-case but it still might be safer to add it. More seriously, you might need to fine-tune the spacing around the different document elements in `\mycv`, but it's hard to guess what to do without knowing what is  inside these macros.